# CakePHP: How can I read in controller the string value of a flash message if set?

Tags: session, cakephp, flash-message

I need to know this so I can append messages (flashes) if needed.

This way I can give the user the full feedback and avoid one flash being overwritten (in a redirect, for ex, where the last controller, usualy, can do that).

I read the documentation and I did't find any option to be given in setFlash() in order to require this appending.

I know there is a Session::read(), but I do not know what key to search for..

Thank you!

Comment: debug($_SESSION) and you will know the key.

Comment: Or just looking at the src http://api.cakephp.org/view_source/session-component#line-126

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is:

```
$this->Session->read('Message');
```

Message is the key that hold the session messages for the current user, be it flash messages or auth messages. A simple pr($this->Session->read()) will give you output similar to:

```
Array(
    ['Auth'] => array(
        ... your auth keys and values here
    ),
    ['Message'] => array(
        ['flash'] => ... your current flash message array (if any)
        ['auth'] => ... your current auth message array (if any)
    )
)
```

Although I am not sure why you are worried. When you do

```
$this->Session->setFlash('your message');
$this->redirect('/');
```

Even if you do have a redirect, the session message will persist and will display on the redirected page. You just need to make sure you are outputting the flash messages.

Comment: skaa, I have described the reason why I am worried. In consists in the situation when I set a flash before a redirect, and in that controller (that I am redirecting to) overwrites the flash. At some point I intend to append the last one to the one before it, so the user doesn't miss the first one.

Comment: Well instead of modifying the original flash array directly and each time inside a controller what you could do is have a different function:
`$this->_appendToFlash(); // in app_controller`
and you could modify your original `Message.flash.message` key inside this function and still be able to rewrite the flash message using `$this->Session->setFlash();` whenever needed.

Answer (score 1):

The flash message could be retrieved by using this :

```
$message = $this->Session->read('Message.flash.message');
echo $message;
```